# Javascript error: Invalid regular expression flags

Tags: javascript, runtime-error, expression

So I have an error in my code that's saying `Invalid regular expression flags`. The line at fault is this one: `ctx.drawImage(/Users/aUser/Desktop/NightSquare.png, 200, 200);`, but aUser is replaced with my actual name (changed for privacy). I'm running on a mac and I think I know what the problem is (I didn't include `MacIntosh HD`), but I'm not sure. How do I fix this?
Additional notes: The `/Users/` part of the code is highlighted in red in my text editor (the same color as a string).

Comment: Maybe the browser thinks it's an expression?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Any thing in between `/` & `/` is treated as a regular expression in Javascript. There are 2 ways of creating regular expressions in JavaScript.

```
var myRegEx = new RegExp("pattern") ;
var myRegEx = /pattern/ ;
```

So using `/Users/aUser/Desktop/NightSquare.png` is actually leading to your code being interpreted as some regular expression creation which you do not intend.
Just make it a string literal( using `""` or `''`) and it will be fine.

In case `aUser` is a variable ,use the following string concatenation-

```
"/Users/"+aUser+"/Desktop/NightSquare.png"
```

Comment: I did the same thing while passing a path to a function.  I've done it a million times correctly, but the IDE didn't flag it as a problem when I forgot the quotes because it thought it was a regex.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 4):

Strings need to be in quotes:

```
ctx.drawImage("/Users/aUser/Desktop/NightSquare.png", 200, 200);
```